# Convert time in SQL to 12 hour format WITH seconds on

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a script that I am using to populate a time dimension table and I would like to have a column for the time in 12 hour format.

I know this can be done by doing something along the lines of

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),[FullTime],100)
```

Where `[FullTime]` is a column containing a `TIME` field in HH:MM:SS format.

But this gives the following result `2:30pm` and I would like `2:30:47PM`, note the inclusion of seconds.

I know I could build this up using substrings etc. but I wondered if there was a prettier way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Use 120 or 121 instead of 100  in `convert`. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: try this `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),9)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [FullTime], 108) 'hh:mi:ss'
```

[Taken from here](http://sqlhints.com/tag/time-in-12-hour-format/)

This will give you a column 'today' followed by the time value you seek 'hh:mi:ss'

Comment: Not sure if I have some wrong setting but this is displaying it in 24 hour date format, i.e 1pm is coming up as 13 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tstTime datetime
set @tstTime = GetDate()

Select
@tstTime
,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(26), @tstTime, 109),1,20),RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(26), @tstTime, 109),2))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that comes through as 24hr format, I want mine to appear in 12hr format i.e. 5 past 2 in the afternoon would appear as 2:05:00PM

Comment: Gotcha ... revised the solution.  Did not see a specific format number for what you want exactly so I had to build it with string functions

Answer (score 0):

If having also milliseconds is not a problem for you, you can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, [FullTime], 109)
```